# Setting up Elastic Beanstalk on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After doing some research on scalability I recently decided to deploy my rails app via AWS instead of Heroku. Elastic Beanstalk seems fairly easy to use but the problem I'm running into is I can't figure out how to install Elastic Beanstalk. I'm developing on a remote AWS ubuntu 12.04 instance. Does anyone know the apt-get lines to install eb from the command line? Everything I find on Amazon and various guides point me to downloading/installing on my local PC, but I really want to install it on my remote instance that I'm developing on.

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html). I haven't tried CLI for deploying on Elastic Beanstalk but I am sure that it works.

Comment: The problem is that just gives me a download for my pc. Rather than a command to install it

Comment: You can use `SCP` to transfer the files to your remote server and follow the installation steps over there.

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks for your help!